# Find file for given line number when given an error

Tags: vimrc, error

I'm trying to debug my Vimrc config files but I can't find the file where the error is coming from, is there a way to find the file that the line is coming from?

For example, I'm given this error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>28_HL:
line   43:
E254: Cannot allocate color 0
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg= gui=NONE cterm=NONE
```

This doesn't tell me where the file that the error is occuring is, I have tried doing `vim -V9myvim.log` and rooting for the error which gives me this:

```
line 15: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
continuing in /Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/gruvbox/colors/gruvbox.vim
Searching for "/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/vim-snipmate/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/vim-javascript/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/tern_for_vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/vim-coffee-script/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/jedi-vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/ale/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/vim-markdown/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/Users/thermatix/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
                                                               Error detected while processing function <SNR>28_HL:
line   43:
E254: Cannot allocate color 0
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg= gui=NONE cterm=NONE
finished sourcing /Users/thermatix/dotfiles/tag-vim/vim/plugged/gruvbox/colors/gruvbox.vim
continuing in /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
Executing ColorScheme Auto commands for "gruvbox"
```

But this isn't that helpful because before it was `<SNR>32_HL`, then I removed tabular (which was the last loaded plugin before the error) and it change to `<SNR>28_HL`.

Is the error in `Searching for "/Users/thermatix/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"`?

Can't be because there is no after folder.

I also tried doing `grep -r 'ctermbg= gui=NONE cterm=NONE' .vim/` but that found nothing, and grep-ing for the individual attributes found nothing that seem to be related to the error.

I've also tried using `vim -D` to try and step through but again, it seems to jump lines till the error happens without actually staging where the error is, so I can't tell where the problem lies, you just get this:

```
Entering Debug mode.  Type "cont" to continue.
/Users/thermatix/.vimrc
line 1: so ~/.vim/vimrc.vim
>
>n
Error detected while processing function <SNR>28_HL:
line   43:
E254: Cannot allocate color 0
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg= gui=NONE cterm=NONE
/Users/thermatix/.vimrc
line 2: End of sourced file
>
```

So how do I find where the error is coming from? I mean, telling me the line number is all well and good but it's useless without the file that it's coming from.

If you find the need, my vim config files can be found [here](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/tree/master/tag-vim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the error in Searching for
>   "/Users/thermatix/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"?
>
> Can't be because there is no after folder.

Actually the problem may be that some plugin expects the folder to exist.

> I also tried doing grep -r 'ctermbg= gui=NONE cterm=NONE' .vimrc/ but
>   that found nothing, and grep-ing for the individual attributes found
>   nothing that seem to be related to the error.

You should try grep in `~/.vim`.

In any case, you should follow the procedure in ["How do I debug my vimrc file?"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) (or the procedure at [Vim faq-2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq%2d2%2e5)). It will allow you to find which line on your `_vimrc` or plugin triggers the problem.

---

**Edit:**

> So there's no way to get vim to spit out a file alongside the line
>   number?

I'm not aware of any Vim option that would include the file name; by default it includes only the function name, which in this case is `<SNR>28_HL`. Note the `<SNR>28_` means it is a script-local function (see [`:help <SNR>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3cSNR%3e)).

That being said, I usually find quite easy and straightforward to follow the procedures in the link above. If you still prefer to avoid it, you should try to improve your use of the debugger:

> I've also tried using vim -D to try and step through but again, it
>   seems to jump lines till the error happens without actually staging
>   where the error is, so I can't tell where the problem lies, you just
>   get this:
>
> ```
> Entering Debug mode.  Type "cont" to continue.
> /Users/thermatix/.vimrc
> line 1: so ~/.vim/vimrc.vim
> >
> >n
> Error detected while processing function <SNR>28_HL:
> line   43:
> E254: Cannot allocate color 0
> E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg= gui=NONE cterm=NONE
> /Users/thermatix/.vimrc
> line 2: End of sourced file
> >
> ```

Instead of using `next` in the line sourcing the `vimrc.vim`, you should try to `step` -- details can be found at [`:help >step`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3estep).

Comment: I made a slight mistake, It was `.vim` and not `.vimrc` not sure why I typed that but thanks for pointing that out, still doesn't change that it found nothing.

Comment: Oh, I see. Anyway, the main answer to your question are the links in the last line. The basic idea is to remove settings/plugins through binary search until you find the culprit. Let me know the results when you try them.

Comment: So there's no way to get vim to spit out a file alongside the line number?

Comment: Note: Use `:scriptnames` to find out, which script uses the `<snr>28` prefix. That is usually faster finding the error than using the debugger.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt very nice, I didn't know the index in `scriptnames` would match the `SNR` identifier.

Comment: that is documented at `:h <SNR>`